# Packing args in taquito to match sp.pack / PACK

Tags: smartpy, michelson, taquito

How can i pack on taquito side params so that they match what i would get in smartpy with sp.pack?
Say i have params two ints and a string: 1, 3, "something"
What do i need to do in taquito to get same bytes as i would with sp.pack(1, 3, "something").

We have a pay-gas-by-proxy system so we need this in order to compute sig of params on frontend side and then check it in smartpy.

Answer (score 1):

In SmartyPy -

```
record = sp.record(x=1,y=3,z="something")
bytes = sp.pack(record)
pprint(vars(bytes))
```

gives something like -

```
{'__initialized': True,
 '_f': 'pack',
 '_l': [(record ("my_contract.py" 6) (x (literal (intOrNat 1) ("my_contract.py" 6))) (y (literal (intOrNat 3) ("my_contract.py" 6))) (z (literal (string "something") ("my_contract.py" 6)))),
        <smartpy.LineNo object at 0x103593340>],
 'attributes': {},
 'onUpdateHandlers': [],
 'opens': {}}
```

In taquito Michel codec package we have pack and packDataBytes, see example below -

```
const data: MichelsonData = {
    prim: 'Pair', args: [{ int: '1' }, { int: '3' }, { string:"something" }]
};

const typ: MichelsonType = {
  prim: 'pair', args: [{ prim: 'int' }, { prim: 'int' }, { prim:"string" }]
};

const packedBytes = packDataBytes(data, typ);
// { bytes: "0507070707000100030100000009736f6d657468696e67" }
```

both give you different format in terms of bytes. I would like to understand  your needs and how you want to equate taquito bytes representation with SmartPy's representation.

Kunal

Comment: I copy-pasted your Taquito example, and `packedBytes.bytes` is `0507070001070700030100000009736f6d657468696e67` when I run it, which has a different prefix from your example. Only `sp.pack` gives the bytes you showed. Did something change?

Only difference is I'm using JS instead of TS, and I imported like `const { packDataBytes } = require('@taquito/michel-codec')`.