# Packing and signing a payload in Taquito

Tags: taquito, signature, pack

I'm trying to call a contract method that checks a signature against the chain ID, contract address, caller, and params. The contract lives at [KT1XoT3RTkXCN2y25e635WeEmjN4xszQWtq6](https://tzkt.io/KT1XoT3RTkXCN2y25e635WeEmjN4xszQWtq6/storage/102045) on mainnet, and [here](https://smartpy.io/ide?code=eJy1WG1v2zYQ_u5fwanAIrWOa3VNgwVzsTTAAixrgDbBhqUICFqiEsV6m0glcYbtt@@OpChRVuJsxYwiNu_Iu@deeWyaV2UtichZLas1YYKIajKJMiYE@cjqFZdVxiLui2p2VBayZpEMDiYEPjFPCKVpkUpKfcGzZErK5c1KTknOJYuZZPCLFeyK11OScG6O4Qd3z_Ckb0n4UcfJwohxWK1I4Frp7gatCflGp8MWd6wSwAQzlukVzVnlyxVfL2B9fsoAs7xlWcPV@jOPyjr2UyEaXivKYRzXXAhjIGV52RSyO6upadxR7uUDrXhNFUeRPzaSP0xJXa5ZJlMuur1RzZksB4qqZnli4MF3ELjWRKhfGbs3x4_LBV8DB_461MBZqcWPIJ5DTNe0KtNC2qiis0xEK1azXPRDV81ueZ0ma9_XvFnfJ@Q9mQfkW2KZ1l7yfmFYG5wfFuTN3jwIAjc_EvaGQr4VIuG1QjPDqM9MjgEOwYsYc0v9zBLKrPP6wNJ4QNBIB8qUaJUkX7q1cfOlzpt6mBatficpRlT1EmQDmZsohu0Q@zkzdF2XPIZjljZ_DFmvxkxuM@nVgoSTrYkRlVnGI_loboD_0FcDhxoQuACbLyd2vyzP0qvC8W50zVJDUT@VkyLTeDTdjbUOQssxCaFxuHo76ysWrXisj@BvX@PoNpSrFgGPVlQAj8mmhh4IkowvbU5Z7tTIDfqlkibk73J10Cs9ICYsze5See17H1hMQIAXTEbqy6nXF0RRsVxAJrQSYgouFYT_0bAMnEmqOo04gczRCecIwAZujiyUcY1MMzED7FSWNMfuhFsSIfGLx@mtNneQi8DTe8MgmJUVL6goc@5D8ara3hJ6t1d8gx2hc9fAbyPq8QQwUT0cPJi4HR5VtxaSrzHFEesg05GIWBY1GZMce6wgrIi7Et2EpLtxH91LY1vXAV_1agZvSvKahNDWN4V1RxZkIONlp@71VgWbd0FnHlZRZxDm1elP522jcSHpktPKbOt5JLcc@NudrFDoqzyHVqRcPa7cGmaHjXEEbCl866JdMgT0PERqSkCf6GvgcXdovsJiwr77lGcwKGOlgKKcolGpzQQFEf4md5eEY1KeeZ06fdVtp70ry2h4@qJgRcQz@sxBwupSrWm0hVwahz7RZZ7uLl_rgydVolueA6qDE_PssRPbvdtUcIpTyJntzn3Et6ZWxkYC3bC0SDeXtuAxMv8PTN10P4YLMWyEdook@FOXOYXxvqTdGOaObD2Ikbn3zbyBQM9_SfU90j4LlEB3WJf3epwfbh2@EwDE4GC54kXv4RDMMrYuG@n7Huz1pgS_9RZYeFqeF6iPsa8Xj8VO64Ad50LrR6BzUTXLEO6XbvbSlrUO0zYN9xiT3PEW7VIOtva0ng4uA_jXu2vnsIhg3MFUgjqjkoP8guWYcl7vvQkjEUZVsU2AXmCc04ITZgdCRY9CODt4qpoS9r2T8_DXo_N3v_92enF8clbkNyw@vkhO7ve_b45Ow@Lm5_0H0KUBQq_6k4QHxDskZ7JOiyuP_AU2wTNRp0X_oWgoep8@b3XKhzD6xMN3R7H4cFEcP7xld_X12@q7Jrw_2S_3Ph1W8R7qDOc6NCLiBavTkhAz3ghJW5o_2AJzeqQHdZbhsNedYJGa5X3vEBmePrcsl2NbPpRLsyEKVfPx24DB7tAtD03pDx7h3L47zHX0by3XMzQcBnw4UANiusKh2h337LSHE1rdFL4d9uGcxv8fnhBg8ubrAYF0VP1@0G9rrefJNwOM8JqTsxXvvRcmbRsDb0m6shZ3hPbhnoNeaHCqv6GiAZ0mZZ0zBL_zmd3tGKaNoH2W6TG7@28BYrEgvvRq04tT0p8rjK__ARpzsZo-) is the code. (It's the Hic Et Nunc SwapV2 contract modified to restrict purchases by private key using signatures.)

First I called the `swap` method:

```
    @sp.entry_point
    def swap(self, params):
        sp.verify((params.objkt_amount > 0) & ((params.royalties >= 0) & (params.royalties <= 250)))
        self.fa2_transfer(self.data.objkt, sp.sender, sp.self_address, params.objkt_id, params.objkt_amount)
        self.data.swaps[self.data.counter] = sp.record(issuer=sp.sender, objkt_amount=params.objkt_amount, objkt_id=params.objkt_id, xtz_per_objkt=params.xtz_per_objkt, royalties=params.royalties, creator=params.creator, pubKey=params.pubKey)
        self.data.counter += 1
```

with pubkey `edpkuEFWHq3MWMjaZo9aEiYPno2feDb745aYepH7DWDbzBFqbxt4wF`. `swaps` now has a single entry with id 1.

The buy method I'm now calling starts with this code in SmartPy that checks the sig:

```
    @sp.entry_point
    def collect(self, params):
        swap = self.data.swaps[params.swap_id]

        toSign = sp.record(chain = sp.chain_id, contract = sp.self_address, sender = sp.sender, swap = params.swap_id)
        packed = sp.pack(toSign)
        ok = sp.check_signature(swap.pubKey, params.signature, packed)
        sp.if ~ok:
          sp.failwith("Bad sig")
```

Ok. All the above works in a SmartPy unit test ([full code here](https://smartpy.io/ide?code=eJy1WG1v2zYQ_u5fwanAIrWOa3VNgwVzsTTAAixrgDbBhqUICFqiEsV6m0glcYbtt@@OpChRVuJsxYwiNu_Iu@deeWyaV2UtichZLas1YYKIajKJMiYE@cjqFZdVxiLui2p2VBayZpEMDiYEPjFPCKVpkUpKfcGzZErK5c1KTknOJYuZZPCLFeyK11OScG6O4Qd3z_Ckb0n4UcfJwohxWK1I4Frp7gatCflGp8MWd6wSwAQzlukVzVnlyxVfL2B9fsoAs7xlWcPV@jOPyjr2UyEaXivKYRzXXAhjIGV52RSyO6upadxR7uUDrXhNFUeRPzaSP0xJXa5ZJlMuur1RzZksB4qqZnli4MF3ELjWRKhfGbs3x4_LBV8DB_461MBZqcWPIJ5DTNe0KtNC2qiis0xEK1azXPRDV81ueZ0ma9_XvFnfJ@Q9mQfkW2KZ1l7yfmFYG5wfFuTN3jwIAjc_EvaGQr4VIuG1QjPDqM9MjgEOwYsYc0v9zBLKrPP6wNJ4QNBIB8qUaJUkX7q1cfOlzpt6mBatficpRlT1EmQDmZsohu0Q@zkzdF2XPIZjljZ_DFmvxkxuM@nVgoSTrYkRlVnGI_loboD_0FcDhxoQuACbLyd2vyzP0qvC8W50zVJDUT@VkyLTeDTdjbUOQssxCaFxuHo76ysWrXisj@BvX@PoNpSrFgGPVlQAj8mmhh4IkowvbU5Z7tTIDfqlkibk73J10Cs9ICYsze5See17H1hMQIAXTEbqy6nXF0RRsVxAJrQSYgouFYT_0bAMnEmqOo04gczRCecIwAZujiyUcY1MMzED7FSWNMfuhFsSIfGLx@mtNneQi8DTe8MgmJUVL6goc@5D8ara3hJ6t1d8gx2hc9fAbyPq8QQwUT0cPJi4HR5VtxaSrzHFEesg05GIWBY1GZMce6wgrIi7Et2EpLtxH91LY1vXAV_1agZvSvKahNDWN4V1RxZkIONlp@71VgWbd0FnHlZRZxDm1elP522jcSHpktPKbOt5JLcc@NudrFDoqzyHVqRcPa7cGmaHjXEEbCl866JdMgT0PERqSkCf6GvgcXdovsJiwr77lGcwKGOlgKKcolGpzQQFEf4md5eEY1KeeZ06fdVtp70ry2h4@qJgRcQz@sxBwupSrWm0hVwahz7RZZ7uLl_rgydVolueA6qDE_PssRPbvdtUcIpTyJntzn3Et6ZWxkYC3bC0SDeXtuAxMv8PTN10P4YLMWyEdook@FOXOYXxvqTdGOaObD2Ikbn3zbyBQM9_SfU90j4LlEB3WJf3epwfbh2@EwDE4GC54kXv4RDMMrYuG@n7Huz1pgS_9RZYeFqeF6iPsa8Xj8VO64Ad50LrR6BzUTXLEO6XbvbSlrUO0zYN9xiT3PEW7VIOtva0ng4uA_jXu2vnsIhg3MFUgjqjkoP8guWYcl7vvQkjEUZVsU2AXmCc04ITZgdCRY9CODt4qpoS9r2T8_DXo_N3v_92enF8clbkNyw@vkhO7ve_b45Ow@Lm5_0H0KUBQq_6k4QHxDskZ7JOiyuP_AU2wTNRp0X_oWgoep8@b3XKhzD6xMN3R7H4cFEcP7xld_X12@q7Jrw_2S_3Ph1W8R7qDOc6NCLiBavTkhAz3ghJW5o_2AJzeqQHdZbhsNedYJGa5X3vEBmePrcsl2NbPpRLsyEKVfPx24DB7tAtD03pDx7h3L47zHX0by3XMzQcBnw4UANiusKh2h337LSHE1rdFL4d9uGcxv8fnhBg8ubrAYF0VP1@0G9rrefJNwOM8JqTsxXvvRcmbRsDb0m6shZ3hPbhnoNeaHCqv6GiAZ0mZZ0zBL_zmd3tGKaNoH2W6TG7@28BYrEgvvRq04tT0p8rjK__ARpzsZo-)).

```
@sp.add_test(name = "Marketplace")
def test():
    # define a contract
    c1 = Marketplace(sp.address("KT1VCT6YWNZGKSnmjadGZfKx79uCN1njJ7ze"), sp.map({ 1: "A String" }, tkey = sp.TNat, tvalue = sp.TString), sp.address("tz1cQe16CdsBZnGz4awrh4p3u1xK7o5QApd5"), 10)
    scenario  = sp.test_scenario()
    scenario += c1
    alice = sp.test_account("Alice")
    bob = sp.test_account("Bob")
    c1.swap(objkt_id = 1, objkt_amount = 1, royalties = 10, creator = sp.address("tz1cQe16CdsBZnGz4awrh4p3u1xK7o5QApd5"), pubKey = bob.public_key, xtz_per_objkt = sp.tez(1)).run(sender = bob)
    toSign = sp.record(chain = sp.chain_id, contract = c1.address, sender = bob.address, swap = 500000)
    packed = sp.pack(toSign)
    sig = sp.make_signature(
      secret_key = bob.secret_key,
      message = packed,
      message_format = 'Raw'
      )
    c1.collect(swap_id = 500000, signature = sig).run(sender = bob, amount = sp.tez(1))
```

But now I'm trying to do it for real using Taquito. [This answer](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/questions/3806/packing-args-in-taquito-to-match-sp-pack-pack) told me how to pack the data.

```
const { ChainIds } = require('@taquito/taquito')
const { InMemorySigner } = require('@taquito/signer')
const { bytes2Char, char2Bytes } = require('@taquito/utils')
const { packDataBytes } = require('@taquito/michel-codec')

;(async () => {
// testing pub-priv keypair I don't mind sharing
const pubKey = "edpkuEFWHq3MWMjaZo9aEiYPno2feDb745aYepH7DWDbzBFqbxt4wF"
const signer = new InMemorySigner("edskRkGz8EzThsHTrtwpU2vL6XYa4o5XBHwuWQ6P3Z8vL9uhi2YvRMfrJFZcVFLwjN753UrorY62XAgAdTFoV2vPzm4vqDSXQQ");

// We'll send this as tz1Tb7cHhKeyKRYU9CQTALedbmYQWzdKeUSz
const data = {
    prim: 'Pair', args: [{ string: ChainIds.MAINNET }, { string: 'KT1XoT3RTkXCN2y25e635WeEmjN4xszQWtq6' }, { string: "tz1Tb7cHhKeyKRYU9CQTALedbmYQWzdKeUSz" }, { int: '1' }]
};
const typ = {
  prim: 'pair', args: [{ prim: 'chain_id' }, { prim: 'address' }, { prim:"address" }, {prim: 'int'}]
};
let bytes = packDataBytes(data, typ).bytes
console.log({bytes})
const signature = await signer.sign(bytes);
console.log({signature})
})();
```

This yields

```
{
  signature: {
    bytes: '0507070a000000047a06a77007070a0000001601feb0d69309e346326f49161325bc134604f8ef190007070a0000001600005733dcd6c0d5c1ce9208cf1176b0e04608dfb15e0001',
    sig: 'sigSmjBUs7tBXFe5WyrdJveGJ4uS53eBbf5fyTWU9sA6PpK7DYuMnZ85xTnwyWFun1q1PhcJMkYXs1xWvifjUtTYpLGPhABg',
    prefixSig: 'edsigtcbCJY62A7iHhGWGzfA7bZaagG9ycpUFTMjCEp9rASQmcwA9QFheD9CNqYbJMNxNGYsKXp97P9pnhJxvKsprebtSDFdSDp',
    sbytes: '0507070a000000047a06a77007070a0000001601feb0d69309e346326f49161325bc134604f8ef190007070a0000001600005733dcd6c0d5c1ce9208cf1176b0e04608dfb15e0001248fd541b9a5557e75e93e130643390496f1b22b6335d7fb33932178a79208d05d849db4135ab839a4cbd6efc7d2b665b0e524673ebcd26bb5948e7533a28101'
  }
}
```

I tried using that `edsig...` value as my signature, which is what the SmartPy test sig looked like. Called `collect` in bettercall.dev. Contract says "bad sig". Am I packing the data wrongly or something? I realize this is a very broad question, just wondering if there's an obvious newbie mistake I'm making.

**Update from 2AM findings**

I tried passing the mainnet parameters into the SmartPy test and obtained this packed value that resulted in the correct signature: `05070707070a000000047a06a7700a0000001601feb0d69309e346326f49161325bc134604f8ef190007070a0000001600005733dcd6c0d5c1ce9208cf1176b0e04608dfb15e0001`. The contract call succeeded using the sig from that! :)

But my Taquito code is yielding `0507070a000000047a06a77007070a0000001601feb0d69309e346326f49161325bc134604f8ef190007070a0000001600005733dcd6c0d5c1ce9208cf1176b0e04608dfb15e0001` as mentioned above. Looks the same except for a few leading "07" bytes. Curiously, [this answer on packing data in Taquito](https://tezos.stackexchange.com/a/3816/8039) shows a different output from what I'm getting, with the same difference of leading bytes. So I suspect Taquito isn't packing data the same way anymore.

Comment: Updated my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The layout is probably wrong. Make sure you use the same record layout in both locations.

```
    toSign = sp.set_type_expr(
        sp.record(
            chain = sp.chain_id,
            contract = sp.self_address,
            sender = sp.sender,
            swap = params.swap_id
        ),
        sp.TRecord(
            chain = sp.TChainId,
            contract = sp.TAddress,
            sender = sp.TAddress,
            swap = sp.TNat
        ).right_comb()
    )
```

Also:

`swap_id` is of type nat: (In this case, it should not influence the packed bytes)

```
const typ = {
  prim: 'pair', args: [{ prim: 'chain_id' }, { prim: 'address' }, { prim:"address" }, {prim: 'nat'}]
};
```

<strike>Hope this example helps: https://github.com/ecadlabs/taquito/blob/1abc6b0fc96c165434e53e3008b7676e3796f337/integration-tests/contract-permits.spec.ts#L70</strike>

The test does what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: This fixed it. Taquito ended up giving me the same value as this SmartPy `toSign` value. Not really sure why, but thank you, I'll take it!